# Would this custom prestige class be balanced? (arcane battlesmith that cannot cast)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew, prestige-class, crafting, dwarf

I've been a DM for a year now. lately, one of my players asked me if there was a way to make magical weapons/armor without being able to use magic... as far as i know, you can't. Craft Magic Arms and Armor requires Lv 5 spells..... so i proposed a custom prestige class, the Yzgramor Battlesmith (he's a Dwarf from the Yzgramor Smithing clan so his backstory backs this up). Here's what i came up with:

Requirements: Base Attack Bonus +5, Craft(Weaponsmithing) 8 ranks OR Craft(Armorsmithing) 8 ranks, Knowledge(Arcana) 5 ranks

Hit Die D6, mediocre Base Attack Bonus, Good Fort Save, Bad will and Ref saves

Specials: 
Craft Magic arms And Armor Feat.(Level 1).

gains a caster level each even class level starting with caster level 1 at class level 2, but no casting slots are gained. these spells are only used for the creation of magical weapons or armor.

An Ysgramor Battlesmith can learn spells the same way a wizard does (they have something similar to a spellbook, in which they write their findings). However, because they are not actually proficient with spellcasting, it takes twice as long to learn a spell compared to the wizard class.

Thats what i've got so far..we play D&D 3.5 ALL content allowed. i use a very high magic setting(anyone can learn to use it if they invest time in learning it) and devine intervention is very common. can you plzcomment on this (if this could work or not and possibly come with suggestions to balance/fill the gaps). My hope is this class would be a viable choice for any melee class but without being (obvously) stronger/better than other prestige class options

[Edit] i took a peak at the tiers and after reading it i felt summarizing the current party would be a good idea:

Wolfgrad Yzgrammor, dwarf 7Fighter(who i'm designing this class for).
Shara Nogard, Drow 5Dread Necromancer.
Hira, Half-Dragon Halfling 3Sorcerer, 2Cleric.
Slimyfist, Locathah 5Ranger, 2Druid.
Ruth, Lycanthrope Lord Wood Elf 3Rogue.

looking at these, i think it doesnt harm to give the dwarf a few extra's. both the lycanthrope lord and half-dragon give big stat increases and a few nice special abilities. and looking at the tier list the other character's classes are higher on the list than wolfgad's, so basically the only advantage he has compared to the group is his faster exp. however, i dont want this class to offset the campaign on the long run. i'm planning to use this campaign for a few more years, so i'm not going to add new thing in a hurry.

[Final Edit] This question has been put on hold, an i'll let it be that way as i already got a long way with the comments. thanks Yall

Comment: Not a duplicate, but it might nonetheless provide an alternative: [Creating items without spells](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44760/8610).

Comment: Not sure if this was ever mentioned as the comments appear to be gone but why not just have them go with an artificer?